# Turbolinks 3 and render a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pushstate, turbolinks

I'm excited about turbolinks3(it allows you to render only a partial and not reload all the body)
You can read more about it from here: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
It's amazing but I've a problem:
In browsers that doesn't support pushState(example ie8/9), I don't know how manage the behavior.
It give me this error on IE8:

```
Could not set the innerHTML property. Invalid target element for this operation.
```

My Controller code is:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    if @post.comments.create(comment_params)
      render '_comment', change: [:comments, :super_test], layout: false, :locals => { comment: @post.comments.last }
    else
      render json:'error'
    end
  end
```

A 'solution' could be that I do:

```
redirect_to @post, change: [:comments, :super_test]
```

But then the problem is that it reply with a lot of data that I don't need!(and the response time is bigger) So I reallt want find another solution.

How I can resolve this problem ?
I've thought about 2 solution:
1) Use history.js / modernizr for polyfill the pushState on old browsers

- But I've tried but I always get the same error(like if I don't have 
     modernizr)

  Webpage error details

  User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)
  Timestamp: Sat, 25 Apr 2015 17:28:52 UTC

  Message: Could not set the innerHTML property. Invalid target element for this operation.
  Line: 26
  Char: 30464
  Code: 0
  URI: https://stark-forest-5974.herokuapp.com/assets/application-83a3aa4fd4a1ee124da87760bfdca86febd4fc1cb8a13167c892a15ce3caa53d.js

2) Find a way for check if the request is done by turbolinks/pjax or not...and use conditional render or redirect_to

- But I've not idea on how I can do it, because turbolinks doesn't send
  a specific header like does jquery-pjax

Any suggestions ? I really appreciate it!

PS: Please don't suggest me backbone/angular/ember/react, I already know them(backbone), but I want try turbolinks.

Answer (score 0):

Your first instinct is right, with IE8 you'll need modernizr. the problem is neither you code or turbolinks here, it's IE8.

PS: Turbolinks doesn't actually replace JS frameworks, you can perfectly use it with one of them if you want. I did use it with React and Angular. Turbolinks just avoids re-loading the same thing several times (wich feels already magic).